# How to use Python to represent the Powershell "ToBase64String" function

Tags: python, powershell, base64

Because I want to call windows shell to run a command and to get the output from Python, I tried to encode the command string in Python, then run it by using

```
> powershell -EncodedCommand <base64 string from Python encode>
```

It will through an error because of the syntax.
The codes in Python looks like

```
s = '''Get-ADUser -Filter ('Surname -eq "aa" -and GivenName -eq "bb" -and Department -eq "cc"') | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName'''
bs = bytearray(s, 'utf-16')
base64.b64encode(bs)
```

But, when I use the Powershell function to encrypt my command string to a base64 string

```
PS > $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("Get-ADUser -Filter ('Surname -eq `"aa`" -and GivenName -eq `"bb`" -and Department -eq `"cc`"') | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName")
PS > [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)
```

Afterward, I can get a valid base64 string to execute this command on normal windows shell successfully.

```
> powershell -EncodedCommand <base64 string encoded by Powershell in last two steps>
```

My question is what's the problem here?
Or do I have another option to address the problem? Like, use the PowerShell parameter of "-Command" to run directly?
Actually, I tried it with

```
> powershell -Command "Get-ADUser -Filter ('Surname -eq `"aa`" -and GivenName -eq `"bb`" -and Department -eq `"cc`"') | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName"
```

But it throughs an error of

```
Get-ADUser : Error parsing query: 'Surname -eq `aa` -and GivenName -eq `bb` -and Department -eq `cc`' Error Message: 's
yntax error' at position: '13'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-ADUser -Filter ('Surname -eq `aa` -and GivenName -eq `bb` -and De ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [Get-ADUser], ADFilterParsingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADFilterParsingException,Micr
   osoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: What kind of encoding are you using in python? They are not all the same. For example, one system using 8-bit Unicode and another using 16-bit Unicode would cause them to be different.

Comment: Does the difference matter? Can PowerShell decode the string from python and vice versa? If you wrote the decoded string to a file, and compared them, what would you get?

Comment: Because of the Python function of base64.b64encode needs a bytearray as input, firstly, I convert the command string by using ```ba = bytearray("<command as above>", 'utf-16'), then use base64.b64encode(ba) to encode it.

Comment: I don't want to call Powershell from Python or call Python from Powershell. My question is 
Powershell
`> $bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes("Get-ADUser -Filter ('Surname -eq `"aa`" -and GivenName -eq `"bb`" -and Department -eq `"cc`"') | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName")
> [Convert]::ToBase64String($bytes)`


Python
`s = '''Get-ADUser -Filter ('Surname -eq "aa" -and GivenName -eq "bb" -and Department -eq "cc"') | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName'''
sa = bytearray(s, 'utf-16')
base64.b64encode(sa)`
They don't give the same output base64 string.

Comment: I am asking why it matters that they are different. The encoded representations can be different as long as they are the same when decoded. Python and .NET represent strings differently internally, so they simply may not encode the same. You see this all the time in the real world with encodings. You can have two PNG files that produce the exact same image but are different on disk.

Comment: Base64 is not "encryption", it is an "encoding". Encryption hides something behind an external factor like a password so that you cannot retrieve it without access to this external factor. Encoding can be reversed by anyone who understands the transformation.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your clarification. I'm going to edit the question and ask it in an actual way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `bs = bytearray(s, 'utf-16')` adds [Byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark):

```
bs[0:2]
# bytearray(b'\xff\xfe')
```

To get the same result as PowerShell, use

```
bs = bytearray(s, 'utf-16-le')
```

Then:

```
bs[0:20]
# bytearray(b'G\x00e\x00t\x00-\x00A\x00D\x00U\x00s\x00e\x00r\x00')
```

which is the same as PowerShell:

```
$bytes[0..19] -join ' '
# 71 0 101 0 116 0 45 0 65 0 68 0 85 0 115 0 101 0 114 0
```

Comment: Yes, that's the thing I want!
'utf-16-le' instead of 'utf-16'.